# HTML/Js/Css - Pick a random element to change color

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, box

This is basically (*kinda*) my first time coding! I'm trying to make an html game to put on a website.

It has 9 boxes, which are blue. And some of those boxes will be orange. Whenever an orange box is clicked, it will turn blue! The task is to make all the boxes blue, as quickly as possible.

When all the boxes are blue, you can click a button to refresh the page, which will give a different pair of orange boxes. I have some code which works, partially.

I cant figure out how to make my code **randomly** pick some of the boxes, to change them to be orange. (*I also haven't made the button to refresh the page*). I'm not too good at explaining or coding, but here is what I have so far.

```js
function setColor(e) {
  var target = e.target,
    count = +target.dataset.count;

  target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#08AED4" : '#D4A108';
  target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;

}
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom: 678px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom: 688px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom: 698px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom: 1355px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom: 1366px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

#box9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom: 1377px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<p type="button" id="box1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box2" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box3" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box4" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box5" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box6" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box7" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box8" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
<p type="button" id="box9" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of coding! You could use `Math.random()` to get a random number representing one of your boxes, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random.
Doing something like: `const boxNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);` to get which box, then getting the box using `document.getElementById`, something like:
`document.getElementById(\`box${boxNumber}\`).style.backgroundColor = "#08AED4"`

Comment: @MarkusMaga Not too sure if I'm replying to you or not, haha. I cant really figure it out. I am using W3schools TryIt editor, and codepen.io. When I paste 
```const boxNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
document.getElementById(`box${boxNumber}`).style.backgroundColor = "#08AED4"
```
into the JS part of codepen.io, It says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: getRandomInt is not defined'.

Comment: If you check the link you can find an example on how to write a `getRandomInt` function! It gets a bit messy in the comments `function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}`

Comment: @MarkusMaga I think I got it working! but its only doing one box at a time, How can I make it pick 3, or 4, or 5 boxes at a time?

Comment: You could use a for loop https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp or while loop https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp to pick a random box multiple times. Since its random you could then of course end up picking the same box multiple times. So you could try making a `while` loop and check if the box you try to change already has the color you want, if so keep looping until you find one you didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function (for one box) and repeat it in a loop for more orange boxes

```
function selectBoxes() {

        var box1 = document.getElementById('box1'); //storing boxen in variables
        var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
        var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
        var box4 = document.getElementById('box4');
        var box5 = document.getElementById('box5');
        var box6 = document.getElementById('box6');
        var box7 = document.getElementById('box7');
        var box8 = document.getElementById('box8'); 
        var box9 = document.getElementById('box9');
        
        var boxes = [];
        boxes.push(box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9); //putting boxes in an array
        console.log(boxes);
        
        
        var boxToChangeNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); //random number from 0 to 8
        boxes[boxToChangeNum].style.backgroundColor = "#D4A108"; //changing style of the selected box

    }
```